# Configurações de sistema em classe estática no Entity Framework

Tags: c#, classes, entity-framework-6

Estou tentando criar configurações para um sistema. Pensei em uma classe semelhante ao exemplo:

***Classe:***

```
public static class Configuracoes
{
     [DisplayName("Casas Decimais")]
     [Description("Informa o número de casas decimais que o sistema irá trabalhar")]
     public static int CasasDecimais {get;set;}


     [DisplayName("Opção A")]
     [Description("Determina o Valor da opção A dentro do sistema")]
     public static int OpcaoA {get;set;}

     //...
     public static int OpcaoX {get;set;}

     //...
     public static string OpcaoY {get;set;}

     //...entre outras, apenas exemplo
}
```

Obviamente, só haverá uma configuração para o sistema. Por isso optei pela classe estática.

Agora, para armazenar essas informações, gostaria de colocar uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

***Tabela:    Configuracoes***

```
      id        |       nome       |  descricao                                 | valor
"CasasDecimais" | "Casas Decimais" | "Informa o número de casas ... trabalhar"  |  2
...
```

***Objetivo: (Exemplo)***

```
 //...
 decimal pagamento = x+y;
 Console.WriteLine("O pagamento foi de: "+ pagamento.ToString("C"+Configuracoes.CasasDecimais);
```

***Perguntas:***

1. É possível utilizar essa estrutura com o `entityframework 6` ? Se sim, como ?
2. É correto utilizar classe estática com essa finalidade ? Outra forma mais adequada de implementar ?

> Observação: Não é uma configuração constante como o Carlos sugeriu, e é necessário salva-la pois pode ser diferente para cada cliente.
>
> Já fiz essa configuração como um objeto, e cada opção como uma coluna no banco de dados. Dessa forma, a tabela fica com apenas uma linha. Não vejo problema nisso, só estou querendo ver se é possível fazer dessa outra forma.

Obrigado

Comment: Você quer utilizar essa tabela nas configurações do seu Entity Framework igual a classe criado pela resposta do Carlos? tipo na hora que o entity framework subir ele busque essas informações na tabela e configure o Entity Framework?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic não... seriam configurações do sistema no cliente, por exemplo, configurar ambiente de emissão de notas fiscais, url, casas decimais que iriam ser exibidas na tela do cliente...plano de contas para determinado movimentos, etc... o entity só entra na hora de salvar essas configurações no banco

Comment: "o entity só entra na hora de salvar essas configurações no banco", ele também deve entrar na recuperação da informação, então, deve existe o seu model para ser utilizado nas telas que precisem de configuração. Não pode ser uma classe Static no Entity Framework, e também se for sistemas web essa classe static vai mais atrapalhar do que ajudar. Trabalhe com Entity Framework normalmente e recupere todas as vezes essas configurações.

Comment: sim sim, faltou a parte da recuperação, o sistema é local, não web, como havia colocado, na forma de entidade eu até já fiz, a dúvida mesmo é se é possível salvar as propriedades da classe como linhas e não como colunas. Obrigado @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Usando um Dictionary? ajuda ???

Comment: nunca usei, vou pesquisar =]

Comment: se for Form se pode usar a classe Static com Dictionary<string,string>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não encontrei solução para o problema proposto. Resolvi criando uma classe de configuração normalmente, e declarando um objeto estático na aplicação. Toda configuração que eu precise, pego desse objeto.

Há ainda a possibilidade de usar `singleton` na classe, mas não testei.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma classe de configuração como no exemplo abaixo usando constantes:

```
public static class Configuracoes
{
    public const int CASAS_DECIMAIS = 2;
    public const int PRECISION = 16;

}
```

E depois configurando o Context, no caso do decimal, definindo o HasPrecision:

```
public class MeuContext : DbContext
{
  protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.Properties<decimal>()
            .Configure(x => x.HasPrecision(Configuracoes.PRECISION, 
              Configuracoes.CASAS_DECIMAIS));

  }
}
```

Assim não é necessário salvar as informações no banco de dados.

Comment: Obrigado Carlos, mas a necessidade é salvar no banco de dados. Essa configuração de casas decimais é só um exemplo, teriam várias outras configurações.